# SSL Confusion on Heroku with Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, hosting

I am confused, regarding deploy application on Heroku.

When I deployed my rails 3.0 it is working fine. It is not asking me for trusted certification but same application I converted with rails 3.2.1 and deployed on Heroku, by default it is access with https, so every time I have to hit on "Untrusted and I know the rick" button.

I didn't wrote any type of code related to ssl.

here is the difference,

heroku create                    - rails 3

heroku create --stack cedar         - rails 3.2.1

Because of stack cedar it is use protocal https?

Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3.2.1, by default force_ssl is true, so first you need to make it false. Here is the step

1. Open config/environments/production.rb and search "config.force_ssl"
2. config.force_ssl = true, change true to false, so now it is looks like 
   config.force_ssl = false

and deploy on Heroku, it will works surely.

Here are the few steps for deploying on heroku immediately. [I am assuming that you are using git]

git add .
git commit -m "change true to false for config.force_ssl in config/environments/production.rb"
git push
git push heroku

and refresh the page, it should work.